# "Front of action" vs "action front"

Tags: expressions

Is there any distinction between "fronts of action" and "action fronts", or are these expressions equally correct and have exactly the same meaning?

Here are some EXAMPLES I found in the Internet.

**FRONTS OF ACTION:**
1.  To achieve their goal they developed a policy based on 7 fronts of action: (1) eliminating waste  ...
2.  Five distinct fronts of action to tackle the antimicrobial resistance threat are discussed in ....
3.  ... open up multiple fronts of action against the impediments it places in the way of ....

**ACTION FRONTS:**
1.  The Chamber works on many action fronts to support community development, and 
2.  Our five strategic action fronts, led by innovations in comfort and convenience as well as our enhanced food and beverage offerings
3.  champions of the different action fronts for building the field of learning analytics

Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: My initial reaction is that there is no difference, but you might want to provide a little more context. (One might flow better *in situ*.)

Comment: Let me warn you that neither one of these constructions is idiomatic (i.e. though a native speaker will *understand* what you're saying, he likely would never put it this way himself). The word that most frequently collocates with *action* is *center*, or *middle*, not *front*. He word *front* is used for wars or weather systems, or methaphors derived from them.

Comment: Examples are now provided.

Answer (score -1):

The examples I have posted indicate that both expressions have the same meaning, and, to find out which of them is more natural for native speakers, I have made searches in the internet combining with words "pennies" and "US congress", typically used by people in the US, more than by people in other countries. Thus, I found that "action fronts" is very clearly the preferred expression!